# Redirect url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5, laravel-7

My website Was run with laravel But its address is displayed in Google in this way

Https://examle.com/public/

**How i can delete (public) from my url?**

This is my .htaccess codes:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
   
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: which server? apache or nginx. which os? windows or ubuntu

Comment: you should have the webroot/docroot of the site pointing to the public folder

Answer (score -1):

Hi and welcome on StackOverflow.

To remove `/public` from the url of your app you will need to edit the `.htaccess` you provided and put it in the main folder of your Laravel project (i.e.: where lies `.env`, `composer.json`, etc.), assuming you placed all the code of your Laravel app in the main domain directory of your Hosting Service. The new `.htaccess` will look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
   
</IfModule>
# All other C-Panel related stuff
```

This will internally map all of your urls to `/public` directory hiding `/public` in browser.

**Remember to not edit or delete the `.htaccess` file inside the `public` folder unless strictly necessary**

You can try the code between `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `</IfModule>` [with this online tool](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

I also suggest to install a local Apache Server (like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/it/index.html)), try to setup a Virtual Host and play a bit with `.htaccess` file to understand how to properly set up your Laravel Project in production.

[Here's a guide](https://medium.com/d6-digital/create-virtual-host-for-apache-on-windows-10-by-using-xampp-8664b0427567) on how to create a Virtual Host on XAMPP. It may be useful as a starting point to start creating one on your own.